# On VirtualBox, how to to access the host CD drive from the virtual machine?

Tags: macos, windows-xp, virtualbox, virtual-machine, optical-drive

In VirtualBox (6.1) on macOS (10.12), I have Windows XP as a guest OS. I can't find how to access the physical CD drive from the guest OS. I've found on the web that in the storage settings of the virtual machine one has to add an empty optical drive and check the "live CD/DVD" option (otherwise this is a virtual drive).

I did that, and tried in the dialog box every available USB port (this is a USB drive): each time the drive keeps reporting as "empty" (even though there is a valid CDROM inside that can be read from macOS) in the storage settings. In Windows XP there are new drive letters for the drives I have added, but reported with no CD when I try opening them. I have even tried, just in case, to add the drive as primary or secondary IDE...

Any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The CD/DVD in the emulated hardware of VirtualBox is not a
USB device, but rather an IDE device. It will connect without
problem to the USB device on the host.

**Prerequisite** : For the VM to read the CD mounted in the
host's CD/DVD drive, go to the VM's Devices tab, select
Optical Drives, then select "Host Drive".
The VM will then be able to read the
CD/DVD which is mounted in the host machine's drive.

**To add a CD/DVD to the VM:**

- Power down the VM
- Right-click the VM and select *Settings*
- Click on *Storage*
- Select "Controller : IDE" and click on the icon for
  *Add CD/DVD Device*

  [image]
- Select to connect the drive to a physical drive
- Click OK.

For more information with screenshots see the article
[Add DVD or CD-ROM drive](https://geek-university.com/add-dvd-or-cd-rom-drive/).

Comment: Do you mean that even a USB CD drive must be set as an IDE device in the settings? That said, as I wrote in the question, *"I have even tried [...] to add the drive as primary or secondary IDE"* (and without success, otherwise I wouldn't have posted the question).

Comment: Yes, since in the VM, it's not "connected" via USB.  The emulated hardware is IDE for the VM.  It will "just work" like this.

Comment: @essjae, well it doesn't work actually via IDE either (I have tried again to be sure, without success)

Comment: Do you mean that "Add CD/DVD Device" works correctly but VirtualBox is not detecting the DVD in it? Questions: (1) In *VM > Devices > Optical Drives*,is "Host Drive ..." (DVD) checked? (2) Is the Guest Additions CD image mounted (this blocks the host DVD)?

Comment: I get it: I missed the "Host Drive...." item in the list, which was hence not checked. It works, now. I was actually wondering how the VM could connect to the physical drive without explicitly telling it to do so... If you update your answer with this I will accept it.

Comment: Done as requested.